# How to render an interactive SVG image on React?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, jsx, flamegraph

So I currently have a Flamegraph svg image rendered on my webpage (crossed out of a lot personal info with blue ink, but that shouldn't matter for the purposes of this question):
[image: Non-interactive flamegraph svg]

The problem is that Flamegraphs are supposed to be interactive, and currently the one above isn't. I verified this locally (I can hover and click on the orange/red/brown horizontal rectangles if I just download the flamegraph svg file and play around with it that way)

I'm currently doing a base64 "conversion"/encoding on the svg file's contents by the way.

How do I get the Flamegraph svg to be interactive?

Here's my current code:

```
...//(base64flamegraph is already being set here from the backend)
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>Title: </h6>
        {base64flamegraph ? (
          // <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: base64flamegraph }}></div>
          <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64flamegraph}`} alt="Flamegraph" />
        ) : (
          <div>Still loading Flamegraph SVG</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

**Edit**: for the sake of a sanity check, the output of `console.log(base64flamegraph)`:
"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBzdGFuZGFsb25lPSJubyI/Pgo8IURPQ1RZUEUgc3ZnIFBVQkxJQyAiLS8vVzNDLy9EVEQgU1ZHIDEuMS8vRU4iICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9HcmFwaGljcy9TVkcvMS4xL0RURC9zdmcxMS5kdGQiPgo8c3ZnIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgd2lkdGg9IjEyMD...."

(the string^ is MASSIVE, so not gonna post the entire thing ofc. But the pattern should be clear)

**follow-up question**: Do I have to convert to b64 encoding or is there a way to directly pass in the SVG HTML contents?

Comment: To make the SVG interactive, consider having it as "real" DOM elements via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, instead of referenced in an `<img>` element.

Comment: @Wongjn how would that look code-wise? Would it look exactly what I have commented out right now? If so, would I need to get rid of the `<img ..` line?

Comment: It would look something like what you have commented out, but you'd probably need to base64-decode the content of the variable first. You could consider getting rid of the `<img>` line.

Comment: How do I base64 the Line `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: base64flamegraph }}></div>` and what's the point of base64 encoding?

Comment: I tried 
```const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: base64flamegraph }}></div>
    );
    const base64EncodedString = btoa(htmlString);
```
and then `return...<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: base64EncodedString }}></div>...` in my jsx return statement.

but it doesn't work?